# How to validate the telerik combobox field against special characters in cshtml page

Tags: c#, jquery, c#-4.0, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
<div class="comb">
            @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("cmbGender")
            .AutoFill(false)
            .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("LoadGenderNames", "Search"))
            .HighlightFirstMatch(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @filterColumn = "Gender", @class = "filterCtrl", @id = "cmbGender", style = "width: 140px;" })
            )
        </div>
```

For Eg: I am having the textbox validation using jquery. Similarly, I need to do for the combobox. Below is the code that I used for the textbox validation against
special characters.

Input Textbox:

```
<input id="LastName" type="text" filtercolumn="LastName" maxlength="55" class="filterCtrl" style="width:135px; height:15px"/>
```

Jquery code for text box validation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id$=LastName]').bind('keyup blur', function () {
        if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,.' ]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,.' ]/g, '');
        }
    });
}
```

Above code works fine for the textbox field validation. But I don't know to validate the combobox. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: where you want to do this validation means onLoad() or onChange()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="comb">
            @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("cmbGender")
            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("ComboBox_onChange"))
            .AutoFill(false)
            .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("LoadGenderNames", "Search"))
            .HighlightFirstMatch(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @filterColumn = "Gender", @class = "filterCtrl", @id = "cmbGender", style = "width: 140px;" })
            )
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ComboBox_onChange(){
    var combobox = $(this).data('tComboBox'); // $(this) is equivalent to $('#ComboBox')
    // Use the combobox client object
    // call here your valodation function.

}
</script>
```

or if want to call it some another event then please refer the following link
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html